# ACLs - what does the number of matches mean?

Tags: acl, multicast

First post here.

In brief I have VLAN 1102 which is used as a multicast source VLAN.  This has an IP multicast boundary to only allow out multicasts to receivers in VLAN 1101.  The reason for doing this was to try and stop the flooding of multicast traffic in 1101 but this hasn't solved the issue and I'm trying to find out why.

I have had a quick look and cant really find what exactly the number of matches in the brackets means.  In the permit case, does the match number indicate the number IGMP requests allowed?  In the deny case, is it the number of multicast addresses blocked by the ACL?

Here's the ACL.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
Standard IP access list IGMP1102  
    10 permit 235.0.0.32 (37414 matches)  
    20 permit 235.0.0.11 (9366 matches)  
    30 permit 235.0.0.10 (9470 matches)  
    40 permit 235.0.0.9 (16170 matches)  
    50 permit 235.0.0.8 (916206 matches)  
    60 permit 235.0.0.15 (9374 matches)  
    70 permit 235.0.0.14 (11422 matches)  
    80 permit 235.0.0.13 (15910 matches)  
    90 permit 235.0.0.12 (1674290 matches)  
    100 permit 235.0.0.3 (837286 matches)  
    110 permit 235.0.0.2 (1809784 matches)  
    120 permit 235.0.0.1 (9555 matches)  
    130 permit 235.0.0.7 (11983 matches)  
    140 permit 235.0.0.6 (9460 matches)  
    150 permit 235.0.0.5 (9422 matches)  
    160 permit 235.0.0.4 (835030 matches)  
    170 permit 235.0.0.27 (261335 matches)  
    180 permit 235.0.0.26 (11554 matches)  
    190 permit 235.0.0.25 (489305 matches)  
    200 permit 235.0.0.24 (840658 matches)  
    210 permit 235.0.0.31 (8 matches)  
    220 permit 235.0.0.30 (10 matches)  
    230 permit 235.0.0.29 (54430 matches)  
    240 permit 235.0.0.28 (114074 matches)  
    250 permit 235.0.0.19 (45032 matches)  
    260 permit 235.0.0.18 (842938 matches)  
    270 permit 235.0.0.17 (698826 matches)  
    280 permit 235.0.0.16 (935768 matches)  
    290 permit 235.0.0.23 (129761 matches)  
    300 permit 235.0.0.22 (115088 matches)  
    310 permit 235.0.0.21 (539982 matches)  
    320 permit 235.0.0.20 (431177 matches)  
    330 deny   any (2066969 matches)
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

The number is the number of packets that matched the particular ACE (line).
So for example, there were 37,414 packets that matched line 10.